Runtime Exception Can not load requested doc: org.apache.xml.utils.WrappedRuntimeException. On loading document inside the xslt
I am handling the internationalisation in XSLT to send email to the customer in different languages. For that I am using the document() method to load the xml  in the variable and try to use it dynamically according to the selected language. But when I am sending email from the java side then it throws an exception "Can not load requested doc: org.apache.xml.utils.WrappedRuntimeException".
This is my XSLT
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <!-- Parameter for selected language -->
    <xsl:param name="selectedLanguage" select="EmailData/bodyDetail/lang"/>
    <!-- Global variable with translations -->
    <xsl:variable name="translations" select="document('translations.xml')"/>
    <!-- Other stylesheet declarations -->
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <!-- Template matching the root element -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <!-- Use $selectedLanguage to dynamically select language -->
                <xsl:value-of select="$translations/translations/language[@lang = $selectedLanguage]/title"/><br/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$translations/translations/language[@lang = $selectedLanguage]/subTitle"/><br/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$translations/translations/language[@lang = $selectedLanguage]/heading"/><br/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$translations/translations/language[@lang = $selectedLanguage]/subHeading"/><br/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

This is my translations.xml File
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translations >
    <language lang="en">
        <title>Title in English</title>
        <subTitle>Sub title in english</subTitle>
        <heading>Heading in english</heading>
        <subHeading>Sub heading in english</subHeading>
    </language>
    <language lang="nl">
        <title>Titel in het nederlands</title>
        <subTitle>ondertiteling in het Nederlands</subTitle>
        <heading>Kop in het Nederlands</heading>
        <subHeading>Subrubriek in het Engels</subHeading>
    </language>
</translations>

And this is my java code
public void prepareHtml() throws Exception {
        // get xml string from the view having data for email
        String xmlString = new ObjectUtil().ObjectToXmlMapper(getContentTemplate().getCommunicationConfig().getXsltData());
        System.out.println("email data:::" + xmlString);
        // transformer object need URIResolver, to turn a URI used in document
        // like,xsl:import,or xsl:include into a Source object.
        TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        tFactory.setURIResolver(new XsltURIResolver());
        // get base path of all xslt
        InputStream i = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(this.getBodyXslt());
        Source xslDoc = new StreamSource(i);
        // setting xml string as source to transform
        Source source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(xmlString));
        Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(xslDoc);
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        // get xslt which has html of email
        transformer.transform(source, new StreamResult(writer));
        setEmailHtml(writer.toString());
    }

